# add simple_format to an Active Model Serializer attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'd like to simple_format the body of my CommentSerializer. I have:

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body 

  def body
    simple_format(body)
  end
```

but this goes into a recursive call. Ideally, I'd like to keep the `body` attribute as there is already front-end code using it. What would be an easy way to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes in a loop because you call `body` from `body`. If you want to format the original model body, you need to use `object.body`.

```
def body
  simple_format(object.body)
end
```

Note that `object` is the reference to the object you pass when you initialize the serializer instance.

Comment: thx, forgot about using object there. have to wait a few minutes.

Comment: This answer is correct. @timpone please mark it as such.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that @timpone!

Comment: @StarWars `simple_format` is not available by default in a serializer, it's a helper. You need to include or redefine it.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I included TextHelper in my serializer `class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` is this the correct way to do it.